# How to iterate two vectors in one for loop?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm only showing my functions because I believe the problem is in my `for` loop.

```
DataStoreVectors::DataStoreVectors() {
}

void DataStoreVectors::addItem(string item1, int item2) {
    videoGame.push_back(item1);
    gameSize.push_back(item2);
}

void DataStoreVectors::listItems()
{
    vector <string>::iterator pv;
    vector <int>::iterator px;
    for (pv = videoGame.begin(); pv < videoGame.end(); pv++)
    {
        for (px = gameSize.begin(); px < gameSize.end(); px++)
            cout << *pv << " " << *px << endl;
    }
}
```

When I try to print out the data in my two arrays, it prints out the name of each video game about 6 times and assigns my `int` values to them like so:

```
Valorant 8
Valorant 70
Valorant 50
Valorant 1
Valorant 26
Valorant 35
Fortnite 8
Fortnite 70
Fortnite 50
Fortnite 1
Fortnite 26
Fortnite 35
Doom Eternal 8
Doom Eternal 70
Doom Eternal 50
Doom Eternal 1
Doom Eternal 26
Doom Eternal 35
Minecraft 8
Minecraft 70
Minecraft 50
Minecraft 1
Minecraft 26
Minecraft 35
Apex Legends 8
Apex Legends 70
Apex Legends 50
Apex Legends 1
Apex Legends 26
Apex Legends 35
Control 8
Control 70
Control 50
Control 1
Control 26
Control 35
```

Is this possible? Would it be better to make a struct? I'm trying to figure out the right way to print out two vectors side by side.

Answer (score 6):

It's quite simple to keep the iterators synchronized in position. Just add another increment in the for loop like this:

```
vector <int>::iterator px = gameSize.begin(); // << Add this
for (pv = videoGame.begin(); pv < videoGame.end(); pv++, px++)
                                                    // ^^^^^^ Add this
```

Ensure that both vectors have the same size, or the vector `px` points to is at least bigger than the other one (`videoGame`) though.

Comment: Awesome! I tried to add another increment for my second vector but it didn't work because I didn't write my iterator correctly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @mozuna495 Glad to help :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a range-v3 [zip view](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

```
for (auto [game, size] : ranges::views::zip(videoGame, gameSize))
{
    std::cout << game << " " << size << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the data is linked then you should make a `struct` from this.
I also recommend giving your parameters a more descriptive name in `addItem` such as `addItem(string gameName, int gameSize)` and maybe rename the vectors to use the plural form such as `videoGames` and `gameSizes`.

Regarding the iteration over two vectors you can iterate over those with a simple int index (this assumes both vectors have the same size as it seems to be in your case):

```
for (int i = 0; i < videoGame.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << videoGame[i] << " " << gameSize[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can increment each iterator in the same loop, but both arrays would need to be the same size, however it's a horrible bug prone approach, your single array of a struct that includes both fields is a far better approach.

Comment: While this isn't bad advice in general, you may consider that one might want to avoid doing such refactorings in a massive existing code base. Be it because it's easy to break something with a side effect, or be it because it would generate an unplanned increase of development (refactoring) efforts. Not everyone starts from a fresh mowed lawn.